# CodeIgniter: How to add css link tag to the head of html page from within a helper

Tags: css, codeigniter, codeigniter-helpers

I've got a helper method which renders some html along with the required **css** and **js** links. I am simply concatenating all the html tags and returning the built string. The helper method is something like this:

```
function display_linkPreview($data = array())
{
    $return = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" class=\"cssStatics\" type=\"text/css\" href=".base_url()."assets/css/stylesheet.css\" />
        <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=".base_url()."assets/js/linkPreview.js\" ></script>
        <div>blah blah<div></div></div>";
    return $return;
}
```

And this is the way I am going to render the outpt of `display_linkPreview` in one of the views:

```
echo display_linkPreview($body);
```

The problem is that all the output of `display_linkPreview`, including the `<link>` and `<script>` tags will be rendered in the middle of HTML page where I have called `echo`. How can I modify `display_linkPreview` to add `css` and `js` tags to the `<head>` of html?

Comment: codeigniter has its own template engine, but you are allowed to use any other template engine you want.  probably the smarty template engine (or some other template engine) will have what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use template style viewing, for example, you have `main.php`

```
<html>
.
.
<?php echo $linkPreview ; ?>
</html>

<body>
.
.
<div id='main'><?php $this->load($main); ?></div>
</body>
```

And your controller could look like this:

```
.
.
$data['main'] = "myview";
$data['linkPreview'] = display_linkPreview();

$this->load->vars($data);
$this->load->view('template/main');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `link_tag`. this will help you to link the css and js.
Something like this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <?php echo link_tag('resources/style.css');?>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

here `resources` is the folder that contains the css file `stlye`